# How to create custom alarm in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

We can create Alarm using `ScheduledActionService`. But there are 2 buttons on it: `snooze` and `dismiss`. 
Can I show my specific window instead of default when alarm is shown? Can i create custom alarm window? With my own buttons. Or can I override clicking on `dismiss` button? I need that user do some actions before he dismisses the alarm.

I can use `NavigationUri`, but user can dismiss the alarm just by clicking `dismiss` without moving to my uri.

Comment: This is purposely not possible.

Comment: I have a cool app idea, but I can't do it if user can just click `dismiss` and i can't handle it

Comment: What functionality do you need? Just have a backgroundservice update a tile, and save the reminder times to disk. If they pass, update the tile. Have worthwhile functionality that encourages them to open your app from the reminder itself. Not sure what specifically your requirements are, but there's probably a workaround.

Comment: I need to create an alarm, that user can dismiss only by entering a captcha or something else

Comment: Why would a user ever want to use your app? are you trying to make an alternative alarm clock? b/c the reminder noise is nowhere near as loud / annoying as an alarm, and so this will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @willmel said, no, this is deliberate. Check out the docs on the related topics etc.

The Notification and alarm pattern is designed that way - you can deep link into your app, no changing or overriding buttons.